# How to merge states from two composition functions?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

How to merge states from two composition functions?
I've read docs and didn't find any examples?

```
function useFeature1() {
  let state = reactive({
    todo: '',
    todolist: [],
  })
  return {
    state
  }
}

function useFeature2() {
  let state = reactive({
    items: []
  })
  return {
    state
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear but maybe [with `toRefs`](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/api.html#torefs).

Answer (score 1):

I've just understood there is no point to merge states. Probably it's better to just name states consistently. Like mainStat, stateWithFeature and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```js
...

export default {
  setup() {
    const mergedState = { ...useFeature1(), ...useFeature2() }

    // do stuff with merged     
  }
}

function useFeature1() {
  const state = reactive({
    todo: '',
    todolist: [],
  })

  return toRefs(state)
}

function useFeature2() {
  const items = ref([])

  return { items }
}
```

But Why? To access reactive data in the template you have to return an object in setup - no merging necessary.

Comment: I guess he wants to access the state's properties in the template, without need to specify to which feature they belong to, so that `feature1.todolist` and `feature2.items`, will become `mergedState.todolist` and `mergedState.items`. Since the state property has been created reactive in each feature, will `mergedState` be reactive too? What I mean is, in case `todolist` will change value within `useFeature1` code, the template which refers to it as `mergedState.items` will be re-rendered?